# Show specific element on buttons click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am in a situation that the user is presented with many different buttons.

When any button is clicked, a different form is spawned and a string is injected in the dom to notify the user which form is pressed.

Pseudocode:

```
<div id="notifier">
  <h1 class="text-center">
     <> SOMETHING SHOULD GO HERE<>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#notifier").hide();  //hide the initial string since no form is pressed at the beginning
            $("#editForm1").hide(); //hides form1 since no button is pressed
            $("#editForm2").hide(); //hides form2 since no button is pressed


            $("#btn_1").click(function(e) {
                    //SOMETHING SHOULD GO HERE AS WELL
                    $("#editForm1").show();
```

When button1 is pressed, form1 is spawned in the dom.
But i also want to inject the string "Form1" inside the div with `id="notifier"`, to let the user know which form is spawned.

How do i do that?

Comment: The jquery web site is chock FULL of example code.

Comment: I would highly suggest exploring and reading over https://learn.jquery.com as well

Answer (score 1):

- Use the `data-*` attribute to store the target selector: `data-formshow="#form-1"`
- Use a CSS class to hide your forms: `.none { display: none; }`
- Use jQuery to select your buttons and forms
- Use jQuery `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to manipulate the `.none` class
- Use `.not()` to exclude specific Elements from a collection:

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const $notifier = $('#notifier');       // the <H1>
  const $buttons = $('[data-showform]');  // the <button>s
  const $forms = $('[id^="form-"]');      // the <form>s
  
  $buttons.on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const sel = $(this).data('showform'); // Get the selector
    const txt = $(this).text();           // Get the text
    const $form = $(sel);                 // Get the form Element
    $forms.not($form).addClass('hide');   // Hide other forms
    $form.removeClass('hide');            // Show target form
    $notifier.text( txt );                // Preview button text into H1
  });
  
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<h1 id="notifier">CLICK A BUTTON</h1>

<button type="button" data-showform="#form-1">FORM ONE</button>
<button type="button" data-showform="#form-2">FORM TWO</button>

<form id="form-1" class="hide">I'm form ONE</form>
<form id="form-2" class="hide">I'm form TWO</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```